# How to learn linux network stacks source code

Tags: c++, linux, networking, stack

Recently, one of my work is to write network stacks using C++ in an OS developed by my team which is totally different from linux. However, I think how a deep understanding of linux network stacks may be helpful to design and implementation a well one.

Any advice or helpful material?

Comment: I would definitely invest in a copy of [Tanenbaum](http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Networks-Edition-Andrew-Tanenbaum/dp/0132126958)

Answer (score 5):

[Unix Network Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411551) by W. Richard Stevens

Comment: Stevens would be my top choice for somebody learning sockets.  However, for implementing a stack, I'd recommend [Tanenbaum](http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Networks-Edition-Andrew-Tanenbaum/dp/0132126958) or [Comer](http://www.amazon.com/Internetworking-TCP-Vol-5th-Edition/dp/0131876716).  IMHO..

Comment: That is a book of how to write network applications in user-sapce. What I asked is some advice on how to write network part of kernel in kernel-space. Thank you all the same.

Comment: If you have a solid understanding of the user space then I would investigate a reference implementation of your target architecture. There are numerous implementations and they will all differ

Answer (score 2):

[LwIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LwIP) or [UIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UIP_%28micro_IP%29), both originally by Adam Dunkels. Particularly `LwIP` - they are small, and well documented, and have been ported to embedded devices. It would take a lot of work to try and learn from BSD / Linux network stack source code.

Answer (score 0):

[TCP/IP Illustrated, Vol. 2: The Implementation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020163354X) It use FreeBSD 4.X source code as real world example.